# Sampling diverse binary strings

Tags: math, binary, discrete-mathematics

What would be a good way to sample N binary strings of length that maximizes their 'diversity'?

Easiest way to generate a binary string of length d is to set each bit independently uniformly to 0 or 1. But this would be equivalent to sampling from the space {0,1}^d with replacement: some of the sampled strings might be the same.

I would like to pick binary string so that the similarity between strings is small. For example, by maximizing the sum of all Hamming distances, or by maximizing the minimum Hamming distance, etc.

Sampling without replacement will increase the diversity. (For example minimal possible Hamming distance will go from 0 to 1)

How to increase diversity further?

Comment: Given an arbitrary sampling, you could try to flip bits that increase your diversity measure (i.e. local optimization).